# Locale powersave plugin & Power Control widget

Tags: app-widgets, battery-life, locale

I use Locale app with powersave plugin. 3G is usually switched off except  during scheduled syncing to save power.

There are occassional situations when I would like to use 3G and I would like switch it on by hand. I would like to use Power Control widget.
I have two problem with it.

- I can't reenable 3G that powersave plugin disabled previously
- I cannot override the behaviour of the Locale. In the Default profile 3G shouldn't be allowed so it would disable it all the time when it's enabled.

For now I can't found any Power Conrol plugin for Locale.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem or do you have any workaround?

Thanks,

Hubi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the developer of Locale.

To get started, please read this article on our website about toggling 3G which should answer your questions: http://feedback.twofortyfouram.com/forums/5655-locale-feedback/suggestions/67867-3g-support-for-network-setting?ref=title

From that article, I think you'll find that using APNDroid will be the best solution: it is free, has a Locale plug-in, and it contains a widget that can be used to manually toggle Internet access on the phone.

Comment: This is a working solution for 3G. Do you have some similar solution for wifi?